# Regex for filename in img src attribute

Tags: javascript, regex

I have url and img tag like these (files can have gif, png or jpg extension):

```
'C:\fakepath\Chrysanthemum.jpg'
'<img src="http://localhost/rootil/uploads/arrow.jpg">'
```

and I want to parse filenames from them, so I get

```
'Chrysanthemum.jpg'
'arrow.jpg'
```

respectively.

My first try is:

```
alert(g.slaves[f].value.match(/\.\w{1,4}$/gi))
```

but it gives me only `.jpg`.

Can someone help me with correct regexp for that situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that should work for you:

```
var r = /[^/\\]+(?:jpg|gif|png)/gi;

var s = 'C:\\fakepath\\Chrysanthemum.jpg \
         <img src="http://localhost/rootil/uploads/arrow.jpg">';

s.match(r); 
// => ["Chrysanthemum.jpg", "arrow.jpg"]
```

Comment: I don't want this: ", "jpg"" just this: arrow.jpg. how is it?

Comment: In above code there is problem, if image name was as: `http://localhost/rootil/uploads/sasd-dsdf-81695329.jpg` it just get as: `81695329.jpg`, how fix it?

Comment: That problem was in the first version with `\w`, but current one returns `sasd-dsdf-81695329.jpg` as expected. Are you sure you use same regexp as the one posted above?

Comment: Close, but I'd add `\s` to your negated char class so that it correctly matches a filename having no path. i.e. `"sentence with file.gif in it."`